# Is there a way to reset my Arena chain without actually losing a battle?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In Tier 18, things are pretty heated in the Arena. Only the top 40% of players advance to Tier 19, while the bottom 60% are put back into Tier 17. The *only* way to actually advance, it seems, is to choose Advanced difficulty for all 7 battles and win them without losing a single unit. This week, I decided to ensure I'd move up, but I had a really bad habit of losing a single unit on my 5th or 6th consecutive map, which meant that streak was worthless to continue, despite winning these battles.

However, I couldn't find any options to forfeit that streak to simply start over. The only way I have found to reset my streak is by surrendering (or actually losing) to an Arena opponent, which benefits the player I forfeit to. Is there a way to reset my win streak **without** actually losing to another player's team (and therefore benefitting them)?

It's worth mentioning that if you surrender before choosing a battle but after redeeming a dueling crest, the game itself tells you that this will not make you lose your win streak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop your chain outside of losing a game.

Most likely due to a loss in the arena not affecting your ranking against other players.

The only benefit they will get are a few feathers, but they won't be beating your rank with the defence victory.

Comment: That's still losing a battle and benefitting another player?

Comment: Oh, without benefiting anyone? Sorry I thought you meant without harming your rank. Then no there is not. I mean, its just a few feathers, not sure there is a need to pointlessly deny other players feathers.

Comment: A loss against another does affect my ranking though? It resets my streak. Without a full streak, there is no chance of advancing tiers.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the point of the question, you were looking to reset your streak and start over. "I couldn't find any options to forfeit that streak to simply start over". I'm just saying it does not directly benefit your opponent's rank if you were going to lose the streak regardless.

Comment: well that's the point I guess. It's not that I was going to lose the streak, it's that my streak was worthless because I would not get through all 7 battles flawlessly. I don't want to give someone credit for successfully defending against me because I still would have won, I just lost one unit.

Comment: Well it does you no harm to help out a little guy, if you want to surrender I would just pick a lower Tier opponent (via picking an easier difficulty) and surrender to them. The lower guys could use a few more feathers each week :) If you really don't want to give anyone credit for anything, just finish off your chain even if it won't be a new high score.